# How to block input while WCF Asynchronous call runs?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm working on an application on Windows Phone, and I am using silverlight.
I have some bugs where the user can quickly press a button twice, which will effectively do 2 WCF calls since the action is called 2 times.

The obvious solution is simply to disable the button until the call completes but I'm wondering if there's a more global solution where I wouldn't have to implement this for every action. My application uses about 50 WCF methods so it would be tedious to implement this for every single action/every screens.

There's also the situation where users can click the phone back button while a call is running and start clicking on other buttons etc...

Anyone know a clean solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: use a boolean variable that will be set to true after first click and to false when result from server has arrived back. In click handler just check the value of this variable, if it is true do not call the service again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a design pattern like MVVM in your application? If not, you probably should.
In this case you could create a bool property called IsIdle or something like it. Then just set `<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsIdle}"`. 
Now whenever you start doing an asynchronous call, set IsIdle to false. This will disable the buttons. When loading is finished set it back to true, so all the buttons are enabled again.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be very elegant, but I think it would prevent any input without creeping all over your views and code.

You could prevent input by temporarily overlaying a transparent rectangle over your screen with `IsHitTestable = true`. You could write a small utility method to push that rectangle on any of your screens and remove it when you want to restore input.

You could also use that screen to eventually show something like a busy indicator when the network is slow.

Comment: Actually this wouldn't work if you just want to block certain operations. A better solution would probably be to have a static property IsNetworkBlocked, and bind it to IsHitTestable or IsEnabled only on the controls that initiate a network call.

Comment: Well actually this is what I went with. Turns out it works great for what I need. It was a breeze to implement since I use mvvm and all my ViewModels inherit from a base model. So I simply added a property called "IsBusy" in the base model and databounded the rectangle visibility to that property. In addition to that, I was able to put a subtle "working" animation in that rectangle as well which gives a very professional feel when my app is communicating with the server.  Thanks Anthony!